# How select XML fields node for all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this :

```
YEAR    int,
Fields  XML
```

My XML column has this structure for all rows but with different values:

[image]

How I can get this result:

```
YEAR         ID           NAME             LASTNAME
---------------------------------------------------
2011         1000         Nima               Agha
2011         1001         Begha              Begha
2011         1002         Jigha              Jigha
2011         1003         Aba                Aba
2012         1034         AAA                BBB
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
 SELECT 
     Year,
     E.P.value('(ID)[1]', 'INT') AS 'ID',
     E.P.value('(Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'Name',
     E.P.value('(LastName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS 'LastName'
 FROM 
     dbo.YourTable 
 CROSS APPLY
     Fields.nodes('/Employees/Person') AS E(P)
```

You're basically selecting `Year` from the base table and then extracting each `<Person>` node from the `Fields` column into an "inline XML table" called `E` with a single XML column called `P` (you can choose whatever names you like for those) that you again query and extract the individual elements from .

Comment: is there any way to select my fields without `CROSS APPLY`? I want to create index view based on this select

Comment: @Nima: no. CROSS APPLY is the way to go to grab **all** XML elements stored in a XML column. I don't know of any other way

Comment: @Nima - Even if you could do this without the CROSS APPLY you are not allowed to create indexed views using XML data type methods.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Consider I don't use `CROSS APPLY` and just use first value of my XML field.Why I can't create index view on it?

Comment: @Nima that is a good question and I don't really know the answer. There are a lot of limitations on views when you want to index them. Perhaps you should add that as a new question on SO. There might be someone that actually knows why.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson :Yes You are right.I wonder why Sql server has Index View.it doesn't create with 99% sql statements